# Using SSJS in journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I had heard that SSJS activities could be used in Journey Builder if Script activities are enabled within Email studio?

Is this true? is there anyway to use SSJS within Journey Builder without having to build a custom JB activity?

For context I want to use the SSJS activity to update records within a DE. No, i can't use Update Contact because the primary key in both DEs are different (unfortunately can't change this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Script Activities can only be used in Automation Studio. They are not an interaction available inside of Journey Builder. To utilize SSJS, you would either need to build a custom Journey Activity or have a call to this script inside an email or message.

Other than that, you can set it up to have the script run in an automation that will affect the stuff Journey Builder is using (Data Extensions, content, etc.) but it will run separate from JB itself.

Comment: Thanks Gortonington! Btw love the blog!